# Understanding Lovász Proof that a Critical Graph with $\chi(G) = k + 1 \implies G$ is $k-1$ edge Connected

Tags: graph-theory

Lovász proves in one of his exercises from Combinatorial Problems and Exercises (1992) that if $G$ is a critical graph with $\chi(G) = k + 1$ then $G$ is $k-1$ edge connected.

In my own words I understand his proof to be as follows:

Assume that $m \leq k - 1$ edges $e_1, ... , e_m$ partition $G$ into 2 subgraphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ which are $k$ colorable by criticality of $G$; that is, assume that $G$ becomes disconnected with the removal of $\leq k - 1$ edges. Then, these graphs can be joined by $k - 1$ edges s.t. $G$ has a coloring in $k$ colors, a contradition. Thus, $G$ is a critical graph with $\chi(G) = k$ $\implies$ $G$ is $k-1$ edge connected. $\square$

Is what I have sufficient to prove the statement? It seems Lovász makes a more rigorous argument about why the union of $G_1$ and $G_2$ is colorable in $k$ colors in his original proof.

Comment: What do you mean by "Lovász makes a more rigorous argument"? More rigorous than what? As far as I can see you made no argument at all, or did I miss something?

Comment: The argument that the union of $G_1$ and $G_2$ is colorable in $k$ colors is made with a very rigorous mapping of 2 sets of color classes in the original proof. I think you're correct that I don't explicitly have anything here. I'm really just curious as to whether I could get away with saying clearly we have at most $k$ colors in $G_1$ and at most $k$ colors in $G_2$ so we can map any vertex of color $n$ in $G_1$ for $n = 0, 1, ..., k - 1$ to a vertex of color $n + 1$ in $G_2$ and obtain a coloring for $G$ in $k$ colors without using his notation.

Comment: You can find a copy of the proof on page 402 of the book found as a .pdf here: http://download.library1.org/main/1200000/f07282161a7b0bbe4627e48961b62b5c/L.%20Lov%C3%A1sz%20%28Auth.%29-Combinatorial%20Problems%20and%20Exercises-North-holland%2C%20North%20Holland%20%281993%29.pdf

Comment: What good does it do to map vertices of $G_1$ to vertices of $G_2$? How is that going to help you color the original group $G$? You already have a coloring of the vertices of $G$ with $k$ colors, but it's not (necessarily) a proper coloring any more after you restore the deleted edges. So you have to recolor one of the $G_i$, by permuting the colors, so that the overall coloring of $G$ is proper.

Comment: I wasn't trying to map the vertices. I was trying to indirectly map the color classes in $G_1$ to different color classes in $G_2$. I guess this is what Lovasz does anyway, I was just looking for cleaner and shorter notation. To the best of my understanding, he basically argues that because you have to take $k$ classes in $G_1$ map them onto $k-1$ of the $k$ classes in $G_2$ you can shift by 1 and obtain a proper coloring.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I took "we can map any vertex of color $n$ in $G_1$ to a vertex of color $n+2$ in $G_2$" to mean you were mapping vertices.